# Is there a way to automatically scale a Delphi form along with all its components?

Tags: delphi

Please note that this is a high school level application.

The method I am currently using to set a component's size and position is tedious and unreliable.

```
btnStop.Width := pnlGUI.Width - (pnlGUI.Width div 3);
btnStop.Height := btnStop.Width div 4;
btnStop.Top := pnlGUI.Height - btnStop.Height - (btnStop.Height div 2);
btnStop.Left := (pnlGUI.Width - btnStop.Width) div 2;
```

This would need to be done for every component using custom ratios based on other components as well as the screen size.

Is there an easier way to automatically scale components with each other with different screen resolutions? All help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: And `Anchors`. You may also want to look at `TGridPanel` and the related controls.

Comment: I remember there was a ResizeKit which seemed to work satisfactory.

Comment: AFAIK, a simple <FormName>.ScaleBy(<dividend>,<divisor>) should do the trick.